# How to load test 10k requests per second using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to load test my website with 10k req/sec for 1 hour using JMeter. I am confused with the values of loop count, number of thread, ramp-up period and duration.

Also will my laptop (i5 8GB) be able to do that? If not what is the alternative.

PS: I checked every question/answer on stackoverflow for this but I couldn't find any help. Please dont mark it repeated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Constant Throughput Timer" and define target throughput and select throughput based on "all active threads".

Define maximum number of users count in your script so that it will be enough for 10K req/sec.

Also if you are using windows machine then I think you will face this issue "https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/"

I will recommend to use distributed testing or use more than 1 machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. The easiest way of configuring JMeter to send X requests per second is using either [Precise Troughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) in combination with the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). The number of threads needs to be **sufficient**, the exact number mainly depends on your application response time, if response time is 1 second - you will need 10k threads, if it's 500ms - you will need 5k threads, if it is 2 seconds - you will need 20k threads, etc.
2. Only you can answer whether your laptop can kick off the required number of virtual users as there are too many factors to consider: nature of the test, the size of the requests/responses, number of pre/post processors and assertions, etc. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and monitor CPU, RAM, Network, etc. usage using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) as if your laptop will be overloaded - JMeter won't be able to send requests fast enough and you will not be able to conduct 10k requests per second even if the server supports it. If your laptop hardware specifications are too low for the test scenario - you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues in play

- test design.  Use more than one load generator.  In fact, use no fewer than three, evenly matched in hardware.   Take one and load only one user of each type.  This is your control set.   If this set degrades at the same rate as your other load generators then you have a common issue, likely the site.  If the control set does not degrade, but the other load generators do, then you likely have an overloaded generator.  On the commercial test tool side of the fence, generating all load from one host have never been considered a good practice in performance testing.
- 10K requests per second.   This is substantial.  I have worked on some top 20 eCommerce sites and I can tell you that even they do not receive this type of traffic to the origin servers.  Why?  Cache!  Either this his a Content Delivery Network where the load is spread across the county, OR there is a cache node directly in front of the load balancer(S) for the site (thing varnishcache of equivalent), OR both for a multi-staged cache.   You might want to look for an objective reference in production to pin this to as a validation poinnt, if and only if (IFF) your goal is to represent end user behavior.  Running a count of requests grouped by second from the HTTP access logs should be able to validate this number.  Also, check the cache plan for fixed assets - it could be poorly managed and load would drop significantly just by better managing the sites cache settings to the client.  If your goal is simply to saturate a SOAP/REST interface to the point of destruction then you might have a better path.
- If you are looking to take a particular SOAP or REST set of remote procedure calls to the point of destruction, consider a classical stress test.   Start your test at zero load, increase with the smallest step interval possible over the longest possible period of time.   The physical analogy to this would be the classical hospital style stress test where a nurse comes around every minute and increases the speed OR the incline on the treadmill OR  both until some end of test condition is achieved.  For a hospital style test that is moving into Oxygen debt, an inability to keep pace, etc...   For your application/interface it could be the doubling of response times from what is acceptable, a saturation of resources in the finite resource pool (CPU, DISK, MEMORY, NETWORK) on the back end hosts, etc...